# using jq to iterate json data

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have some json input data I would like to extract the variable values into something I can paste into my script

**input sample:**

```
{
  "menu": {
    "props": [{
      "name": "foo1",
      "model": "bar1"
    }, {
      "name": "foo2",
      "model": "bar2"
    }, {
      "name": "foo3",
      "model": "bar3"
    }, {
      "name": "foo4",
      "model": "bar4"
    }, {
      "name": "foo5",
      "model": "bar5"
    }]
  }
}
```

**desired output:**

```
AddMenuItem(menu, "bar1", "foo1");
AddMenuItem(menu, "bar2", "foo2");
AddMenuItem(menu, "bar3", "foo3");
...etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
$ jq -r '.menu.props[] | "AddMenuItem(menu, \"\(.model)\", \"\(.name)\")"' file.txt
AddMenuItem(menu, "bar1", "foo1")
AddMenuItem(menu, "bar2", "foo2")
AddMenuItem(menu, "bar3", "foo3")
AddMenuItem(menu, "bar4", "foo4")
AddMenuItem(menu, "bar5", "foo5")
```

`-r` prints raw output (Not JSON encoded).

Unwrapping the `props` array with `[]` and printing the string `"AddMenu..."` for each element in said array.

One can also use `...props | map("AddMenu...")[]` which might be more intuitive.

`\(...)` enables string interpolation between `(` and `)`.